# Does Lua has something like variable?.function() as in Swift or C#?

Tags: lua

#### Hello Guys!

I'm programing with Lua recently and tired about writing some code like

```
if variable ~= nil then
    variable.function()
end
```

I know in C# or Swift, we can do something like

```
variable?.function()
```

Does Lua have some ways to approach this kind of feature?

Comment: You can make `nil` indexable and callable: `debug.setmetatable(nil, {__index = {}, __call = function()end})`  After that you can do `var.func()` without any checks.

Comment: "*tired about writing some code like*" Then you should reevaluate your programming style where you frequently question whether a variable is `nil` or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From "Programming in Lua", 4th edition, section "Tables":

> Lua does not offer a safe navigation operator, and we do not think it should. Lua is minimalistic. Moreover, this operator is quite controversial, with many people arguing —not without some reason— that it promotes careless programming. However, we can emulate it in Lua with a bit of extra notation.

The bit of extra notation suggested could be for your case;

```
((variable or {}).func or function() end)()
```

This checks whether `variable` is `nil` (or `false`) and if not so, tries to access its entry `func` (note that you can't name a function `function` because that's a keyword) - if that doesn't exist, it returns a function doing nothing, otherwise it returns the function `variable.func`. The resulting function is immediately invoked.

I don't think this is very readable though.

Comment: Wow, it does approach the question by the syntax of Lua.
But, yeah, it becomes form three lines of code to one line with a more complicated form.
Anyway, I get the point.
Thanks for answering very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to write a simple utility function:

```
function call_if(func, ...)
  if(func) then
    return func(...)
  end
  return
end
```